# SQLite on a WPF-Application

Tags: wpf, sqlite, c#-4.0

When i want to implement SQLite in a WPF-Application (.Net Framework 4), the programm failed (in the debugger-mode) with this message:

"Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" ist in PresentationFramework.dll aufgetreten.

Zusätzliche Informationen: Zeilennummer "3" und Zeilenposition "9" von "Durch den Aufruf des Konstruktors für Typ "Kasse.MainWindow", der den angegebenen Bindungseinschränkungen entspricht, wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.".

(this is german, here is the version, that is translated by Google-Translator):
 An exception (first chance) of type System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException 'occurred in PresentationFramework.dll.

Additional information: line number "3 " and line position "9 " "By calling the constructor for type Kasse.MainWindow" which matches the specified binding constraints, was an exception.

What should i do?

Greetings,
GreenPepper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably means that you are getting an exception in the constructor of the code-behind class of your window. Try setting a breakpoint and step through your constructor.